# Breeze issue with complexType change tracking

Tags: breeze

I use Angular and Breeze in my app and I use "hasChangesChanged" event for handling a state of entities stored in EntityManager. I have a problem when I have entity with property that is complexType and isScalar=false.
The problem occurs when I make request twice (without changing any entity) and get the same entity. On second request "hasChangesChanged" event is fired with hasChanges=true.
In moment when this event is fired my entity has state "Modified", but after data are loaded that state is changed to "Unchanged".

I've wrote a (Jasmine) unit test. In comments are information which assertion throws error.

```
    var entity,
        hasChanges = false,
        listeners = {
            onChange: function (event) {
                console.log('change', event.hasChanges);
            }
        };
    spyOn(listeners, 'onChange');

    $httpBackend.expectGET('json/SampleEntity?').respond(200, [
        {
            id: 1,
            name: 'some name',
            data: {},
            $type: 'SampleEntity',
            elements: [
                {
                    etype: 'el1'
                }
            ]
        }
    ]);
    manager.hasChangesChanged.subscribe(function (event) {
        hasChanges = event.hasChanges;
    });

    var query = new breeze.EntityQuery('SampleEntity');
    manager.executeQuery(query).then(function (data) {
        entity = data.results[0];
    });


    $httpBackend.flush();

    expect(hasChanges).toBe(false); // OK
    expect(entity.entityAspect.entityState.isUnchanged()).toBe(true); // OK

    $httpBackend.expectGET('json/SampleEntity?').respond(200, [
        {
            id: 1,
            name: 'some name',
            data: {},
            $type: 'SampleEntity',
            elements: [
                {
                    etype: 'el1'
                }
            ]
        }
    ]);
    manager.executeQuery(query).then(function (data) {
        entity = data.results[0];
    });
    $httpBackend.flush();

    expect(hasChanges).toBe(false); // ERROR
    expect(entity.entityAspect.entityState.isUnchanged()).toBe(true); // OK
```

Is this expected behavior? And if not how I can fix it?

Comment: Have confirmed bug with a DocCode test. Reported as D#2672. I'll let you know when it is addressed